# AvalonDock mouse right click menu

Tags: avalondock

How to disable at DockablePane(UI in AvalonDock.dll) mouse right click menu ?please help,i need that.because i want to provide my project with multi-language and it is only in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how *disabling a popup menu* could make your project multi-language?

Anyway:
AvalonDock supports localisation using the standard resource mechanism.
The binary download already contains English, Italian and German translations.
You can add your own.
I suggest you look into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I already solved problem.1st i think i cannot change language and come to diasble popup menu.But learned and added resource file into properties of AvalonDock .it helped .thank you for answer